# How to make Vue-Cli 3 ignore file changes in public folder

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I need to put a lot of js files in the public/js folder.This causes the CPU to reach 100%.

File path:

```
src
public
    - js 
        - 1.js
        - 2.js
        - ...
node_modules
```

These js files will not be updated.
How to make Vue-Cli not observe these files?

I tried this configuration in vue.config.js but it doesn't work.

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      watchOptions: {
        ignored: ['node_modules', 'public'],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing or requiring files in your project from the public js files?

Comment: No import and require.These js files will be loaded directly using an absolute path.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the documentation may be wrong on how to do the ignore.  Try it this way using regex instead. `/public/`

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      watchOptions: {
        ignored: [/node_modules/, /public/],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you probably already know, but be sure to stop and then restart `npm run watch`  or the new config options won't take affect.

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: @vidstige into `vue.config.js` in your package root

Comment: Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy as I had webpack-assets-manifest continously rebuilding manifest.json which causes the entire page to reload.